# Flutter Navigation Drawer + navigation bottom bar how to use right?

Tags: flutter, navigation, drawer

The Bottombarnavbar changes the screen changing the Index of an array which holds my different screens. I get an error when I try to setState for this Index from my Navigation drawer:

I got to the point where I need to setState for the index. I copied just the important parts.

Drawer.dart

```
MyHomePage().setCurrentIndex(4);
```

main.dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  void setCurrentIndex(index){
    _MyHomePageState().setCurrentIndex = index;

  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{

  int currentIndex = 0;

  void set setCurrentIndex(index){
    currentIndex = index;
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
      print(index);
    });
  }
}
```

If you print out the index in `setCurrentIndex` without the setState the index get printed out correct but getting this error when I use setState:

```
setState() called in constructor: _MyHomePageState#61a4e(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
```

Comment: On `setCurrentIndex` method you are creating a new instance on this line **_MyHomePageState().setCurrentIndex = index;**, you should be creating a new instance only on the **createState** method. Better specify what you want to achive so we can help you better.